# Seeking Font Strategies for Silverlight Apps

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, fonts, font-face

As I'm working through an SL3/SL4 application, and starting to work with fonts, I'm finding a lack of documentation and best practices on font strategies. For example:

1. Are there common fallback fonts for
   the supported font set (Arial, Comic
   Sans MS, etc.)? Is there a set of recommendations on fallback fonts between Windows and Macintosh systems?
2. Are there Silverlight-supported
   fonts that will (almost always) be
   on an end-user system, or like 99.5%
   of the time, like "Times New Roman"
   or "Verdana", including Macintosh?
   Are there any sites that list this
   kind of information?
3. Are there recommendations for
   accounting for Moonlight (Linux)
   views of SL apps and the fonts that
   are/aren't deployed with Linux
   systems?
4. Is there a way to determine, in XAML
   or code-behind, if an end-user has a
   supported font on their system? I'd
   like this to run upon entry and then
   change the XAML as a result of
   findings to support the right font
   or allow an embedded one to load.
5. In the documentation for supported
   fonts, it lists a bunch of fonts
   that "*Silverlight text elements can
   use the following Latin fonts if
   available on the local computer*.".
   Does this mean that if I use a font
   that is not in this list, such as
   "Cooper Black", and an end-user
   *does* have this font on their system, they will still need to
   download the font as embedded in my
   application?

Any links or pointers that can lead to at least some of the questions above answered would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is it not possible to deploy fonts with the silverlight application? Add a font as a resource, and then use it within the application?

Comment: It is, I believe. But is that the best way, to deploy all used fonts as resources and default to FontFamily="#arial.ttf" for Arial fonts instead of FontFamily="Arial,#arial.ttf"? I'm just asking here as I don't know of recommended ways that people are creating font strategies. Are they deploying embedded fonts by default? Are they just using "lowest common denominator" fonts (#2 above)? In my apps, I will have *a lot* of fonts, some SL-supported, some not. Some may be on Macintosh, some may not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here we go.  These should get you closer to where you want to be:

1. This is the same as CSS - you'll need to account for 'font stacks'. This is one of the best pages I've seen on the subject: [Guide to CSS Font Stacks: Techniques and Resources](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/22/complete-guide-to-css-font-stacks/)
2. This link is from November 2007 but it still has a great listing: [Complete Guide to Pre-Installed Fonts in Linux, Mac, and Windows](http://www.apaddedcell.com/web-fonts/)
3. The link in #2 is the same - it covers Linux.
4. Not sure about this one. Sorry :-(
5. I believe that is correct, Silverlight only looks for fonts on the end user system that it will natively support. Otherwise, it will need to download the font.

Comment: Great links! That answers most of my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should split your ApplicationFonts into different packages using [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx) (which will be included in the CLR of the upcoming Microsoft .NET Framework 4). So depending on the Users OS it should load the different Font Packages that you need to embed.

Comment: This is a really good read, I didn't even know about MEF and I'm excited to try it out. I'll give you a +1 for this as it addresses my questions in part, but if you post this same answer over on my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047726/multiple-out-of-browser-applications-in-one-application I'll give you full credit there. In partiular, a link off the link you gave is exactly what I was looking for: http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2009/11/29/mef-has-landed-in-silverlight-4-we-come-in-the-name-of-extensibility.aspx for Out-of-Browser experiences and MEF.

Comment: Done, Glenn Block's Blog has a lot of useful tips.

http://blogs.msdn.com/gblock/