# List of fonts in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, fonts

Am using Silverlight 4. I want to populate a combobox with a list of the fonts available. I have searched high and low and can't find a way to do this. Seems be a lot of dead ends. There was a similar question asked in May but with no suitable answer.

Surely its not impossible?

Comment: I've had this question in my head a long time and haven't been able to find a solid way to work with font availability (like lookups, fallback events, etc.). It would be great if there was something exposed like this because obviously SL has the ability to determine availability of a named font in SL4. Here's a question I asked, it had some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169696/seeking-font-strategies-for-silverlight-apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705556/how-to-know-local-font-names-in-silverlight/3504446#3504446) I stick by my previous answer also posted there:

### Generate a lookup table for Silverlight:

There is insufficient information provided in Silverlight to get the full font names *without some form of lookup table*.

I also provided the WPF code to generate such a table, in that previous question. If you do create such a lookup table, for the most common fonts, then the problem is solved.

That creation task just needs to be run on a machine with lots of fonts (or at least the fonts relevant to your target audience).

*Anyone out there (with lots of fonts installed) care to generate a C# compatible table, using my source, and post it for cut & paste?* :)

Comment: Yep. That was one of the questions. I'm thinking that I might just need to provide a DB table where people can install the fonts they want to be available to their users. I could init the DB table with some records for the most common fonts.  Bit crappy but at least they can maintain the list.

Comment: @therealtkd: I just found this list of the most common fonts, that might come in handy for you: http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResults.shtml It's old, but fonts have not evolved as fast as say Silverlight versions :)

Comment: In your other answer, I thought that it was great how you did that - I didn't even know that was available. I was looking up fonts by iterating through all installed fonts and then parsing the actual font file to get information. Your technique was to save me a ton of code and headache. Unfortunately, during the process I discovered a bug in WPF 4.0 in the `FontWeight` (confirmed by MSFT as "not the same FontWeight as earlier versions of WPF", but not confirmed as a bug). But anyway, your code is great, so +1 for that one before and +1 for this one now.